# Como passar mais de um valor para o atributo value?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou trabalhando com autenticação de usuarios, criei dois tipos de usuarios dentro de um mesmo contexto, o usuario comum e o usuario admin, ambos estão cadastrando, logando e deslogando. Estou com dificuldades para retornar os resultados dentro do AuthContext.Provider, pois o atibuto value aceita aparentemente um unico valor.

Aqui está meu codigo:

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import firebase from '../services/firebaseConection'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export const AuthContext = createContext({});

function AuthProvider({ children }){
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=> {
       async function loadStorage(){
           const storageUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Auth_user');

           if(storageUser){
               setUser(JSON.parse(storageUser));
               setLoading(false);
           }

           setLoading(false);
       }
       
       loadStorage();
    }, []);

    //Funcao para logar o usario
    async function signIn(email, password){
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(async (value)=>{
            let uid = value.user.uid;
            await firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).once('value')
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                let data = {
                  uid: uid,
                  nome: snapshot.val().nome,
                  email: value.user.email,
                };

                setUser(data);
                storageUser(data);
            })
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            alert(error.code);
        });
    }
    
    //Cadastrar usuario
    async function signUp(email, password, nome){
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(async (value)=>{
            let uid = value.user.uid;
            await firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).set({
                nome: nome
            })
            .then(()=>{
                let data = {
                    uid: uid,
                    nome: nome,
                    email: value.user.email,
                };
                setUser(data);
                storageUser(data);
            })
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            alert(error.code);
        });
    }

    //Logar e salvar os dados
    async function storageUser(data){
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('Auth_user', JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    //Deslogar usuário
    async function signOut(){
        await firebase.auth().signOut();
        await AsyncStorage.clear()
        .then( () => {
           setUser(null); 
        })

    }
    /*****************************USUARIO ADMIN******************************/
    
    const [userAdm, setUserAdm] = useState(null);
    const [loadingAdm, setLoadingAdm] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=> {
       async function loadStorageAdm(){
           const storageUserAdm = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Auth_user');

           if(storageUserAdm){
               setUserAdm(JSON.parse(storageUserAdm));
               setLoadingAdm(false);
           }

           setLoadingAdm(false);
       }
       
       loadStorageAdm();
    }, []);

    //Funcao para logar o usario
    async function signInAdm(email, password){
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(async (value)=>{
            let uid = value.user.uid;
            await firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).once('value')
            .then((snapshot)=>{
                let data = {
                  uid: uid,
                  nome: snapshot.val().nome,
                  cpf: snapshot.val().cpf,
                  setor: snapshot.val().setor,
                  email: value.user.email,
                };

                setUserAdm(data);
                storageUserAdm(data);
            })
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            alert(error.code);
        });
    }
    
    //Cadastrar usuário Admin
    async function signUpAdm(email, password, nome, cpf, setor){
        await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(async (value)=>{
            let uid = value.user.uid;
            await firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).set({
                nome: nome,
                cpf: cpf,
                setor: setor
            })
            .then(()=>{
                let data = {
                    uid: uid,
                    nome: nome,
                    cpf: cpf,
                    setor: setor,
                    email: value.user.email,
                };
                setUserAdm(data);
                storageUserAdm(data);
            })
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
            alert(error.code);
            alert(error)
        });
    }

    //Logar usuario admin e salvar os dados
    async function storageUserAdm(data){
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('Auth_user', JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    //Deslogar usuário admin
    async function signOutAdm(){
        await firebase.auth().signOut();
        await AsyncStorage.clear()
        .then( () => {
           setUserAdm(null); 
        })

    }


    return(
     <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signed: !!user , user, loading, signUp, signIn, signOut } ,
         { signedAdm: !!userAdm, userAdm, loadingAdm, signUpAdm, signInAdm, signOutAdm }
    }>
         {children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>   
    );
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

Estou com problemas nesta parte, onde tento passar dentro do atributo value o valor do usuario admin como do usuario comum:

```
return(
     <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signed: !!user , user, loading, signUp, signIn, signOut } ,
         { signedAdm: !!userAdm, userAdm, loadingAdm, signUpAdm, signInAdm, signOutAdm }
    }>
         {children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>   
    );
```

Existe alguma forma de passar esses 2 valores no mesmo value? Se sim, por favor me mostre como fazer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Atualmente, você está passando o seguinte valor para o `AuthContext.Provider`:

```
{
  {
    signed: !!user,
    user,
    loading,
    signUp,
    signIn,
    signOut
  }, 
  {
    signedAdm: !!userAdm,
    userAdm,
    loadingAdm,
    signUpAdm,
    signInAdm,
    signOutAdm
  }
}
```

Esse valor não é um JSON válido visto que você não pode utilizar dicionários dentro de um dicionário. No entanto, você pode remover os dicionários internos e colocá-los diretamente no dicionário externo:

```
return(
     <AuthContext.Provider value={{
  signed: !!user,
  user,
  loading,
  signUp,
  signIn,
  signOut,
  signedAdm: !!userAdm,
  userAdm,
  loadingAdm,
  signUpAdm,
  signInAdm,
  signOutAdm
}}>
         {children}
     </AuthContext.Provider>   
    );
```

**Uso*:*

```js
const { signUp, signUpAdm } = useContext(AuthContext);
```

Comment: Obrigado você salvou minha vida <3